# Keycloak registration - custom user attribute value not picked up correctly

Tags: keycloak

I am evaluating KeyCloak, and am trying to configure it as a SAML IDP to a SalesForce client. The SAML flow works fine, however I am running into an issue with new user registration. KeyCloak is backed by a User Federation LDAP (AD LDS).
I have a custom field mapped to the cn field in the LDAP, and have updated the register.ftl in my custom theme. I have also added a mapper, which maps this custom field to the LDAP attribute.

I get an error when I try to register the user, and it looks like the value of the custom attribute is not being picked up correctly.
I cannot find anything useful when I search online, which makes me think that there is probably a silly mistake somewhere that I haven't spotted.

**Mapping**:

- Name: MRN
- Mapper Type: user-attribute-ldap-mapper
- User Model Attribute: mrn
- LDAP Attribute: cn
- Read Only: OFF
- Is Mandatory In LDAP: ON
- Is Binary Attribute : OFF

**Federation provider settings:**

- Username LDAP attribute :userPrincipalName
- RDN LDAP attribute :cn
- UUID LDAP attribute :mail

**Template**:

```
 <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!} ${messagesPerField.printIfExists('mrn',properties.kcFormGroupErrorClass!)}">
    <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
        <label for="mrn" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">MRN</label>
    </div>
    <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
        <input type="text" id="user.attributes.mrn" class="${properties.kcInputClass!}" name="user.attributes.mrn" value="${(register.formData['user.attributes.mrn']!'')}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the error I get when I try to register a new user (I entered 123456 into the MRN field) :

```
14:08:43,514 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (default task-1) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: Could not retrieve identifier for entry [cn=\ ,OU=Emp,DC=MyPortal,DC=TEST,DC=COM].
        at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPIdentityStore.getEntryIdentifier(LDAPIdentityStore.java:546)
        at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPIdentityStore.add(LDAPIdentityStore.java:99)
        at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPUtils.addUserToLDAP(LDAPUtils.java:78)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how this was fixed, but I deleted my mapper and re-created it, and it is working now. The only difference I can see is that the new mapper has its name in lower case while the old one had it in all uppercase. I do not see why that should matter though..